# Rails airbrake undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

I was running my rails application and it was working fine till yesterday but today when i run rails server it is giving me this error.Though my airbrake is also dont have any errors  
[airbrake.rb]

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = APP_CONFIG.airbrake.api_key
  config.host    = APP_CONFIG.airbrake.host
  config.port    = APP_CONFIG.airbrake.port
  config.secure  = config.port == 443
end
```

> ```
> undefined method `api_key=' for #<Airbrake::Config:0x000000073fa1e0> (NoMethodError)
>   from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/airbrake-ruby-1.0.0/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:98:in
> ```
>
> `configure'
>         from /home/techbirds/icare-master/config/initializers/airbrake.rb:1:in`
>   '
>         from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>         from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
>         from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you have inadvertently upgraded to the [new v5 Airbrake gem](https://airbrake.io/blog/notifier/our-new-ruby-notifier). You can either:

1. follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/docs/Migration_guide_from_v4_to_v5.md) to migrate from airbrake v4 to v5, or
2. lock airbrake to v4, in the gemfile, e.g. something like `gem 'airbrake', '~> 4.3.4'`

Answer (score 2):

Have you check the [Migration guide](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/docs/Migration_guide_from_v4_to_v5.md#api-key) on the `github` repo?

```
Old option | New option  | required?
api_key    | project_key | required
.......    | ........... | ........
```

Comment: not working getting the same error   undefined method `project_key' for #<SimpleConfig::Config:0x00000007d8c4b0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: The SimpleConfig class/module has nothing to do with Airbrake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not lock airbrake's major version in `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'airbrake', '~> 4.3'
```

5th version introduced api changes which you're encountering. I'd suggest using above version lock for a quick fix, and then do a migration as described in [guide](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/docs/Migration_guide_from_v4_to_v5.md)